# Le ou La wifi ?

Tags: vocabulaire, genre, informatique, anglicismes

Le Larousse indique sur son site *« wifi »* comme étant un nom masculin. Or de nombreuses personnes utilisent l'expression *« La wifi »*.

J'ai remarqué que le masculin était utilisé pour la plupart des anglicismes (Parking, week-end, et bien d'autres...). Cependant on dit une star, une holding, par exemple.

Ceci est-il dû à une quelconque règle ou est-ce un comportement par défaut que nous adoptons inconsciemment ? Comment déterminer avec certitude le genre d'un anglicisme, et plus particulièrement de *« wifi »* ?

Answer (score 15):

Il y a une règle générale qui dit qu'un anglicisme est masculin, mais tout le monde ne l'applique pas et il y a des exceptions, donc certaines personnes vont dire *« la wifi »* par la loi dite du *pifomètre*, et d'autres vont le répéter car ils l'ont entendu au féminin etc.
Personnellement je dis *« le wifi »*, et n'entends *« la wifi »* que de la part de néophytes.

Comment: Si tout le monde ne l'applique pas, en quel sens cette “règle” est-elle une règle ?

Comment: @Relaxed Il y a bien des lois qui interdisent de cambrioler une bijouterie, et pourtant... :)

Comment: C'est une analogie très parlante qui répond précisément à ma question… mais méconnait totalement la nature des règles grammaticales, qui découlent uniquement de l'usage.

Comment: C'est surtout une règle que beaucoup de gens ne connaissent pas.. L'académie Française peut décider d'un truc, avant que ce soit appliqué...

Comment: Il est intéressant de noter qu'au Québec, le wifi uniquement utilisé au masculin.

Comment: @Tchoupi Et au Québec, on prononce certainement « ouaille-faille », pas « oui-fi » comme en France.

Answer (score 15):

Ce genre est du à la proximité de wifi avec hifi.

Hifi a toujours été employé au féminin à cause son pendant français « **la** haute-fidélité » et aussi le fait que c'est souvent l'abréviation de « **la** chaine hifi ».

Wifi n'étant qu'un jeu de mot construit à partir de hifi<sup>1</sup>, il n'est pas étonnant qu'il soit aussi parfois utilisé au féminin.

<sup>1</sup>  Source [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi): *Phil Belanger, a founding member of the Wi-Fi Alliance who presided over the selection of the name "Wi-Fi", also stated that Interbrand invented Wi-Fi as a play on words with hi-fi, and also created the Wi-Fi logo.*

---

Note: Aucune règle n'impose un genre aux emprunts du français aux langues étrangères. Seul l'usage finit, en général, par retenir un genre. On peut néanmoins parler de tendance, car des études considèrent que seuls un peu plus de 10% des anglicismes sont féminins. Ce chiffre était encore plus grand dans le passé 24,7 au XVIIe siècle, 16,1 au XVIIIe, 14,6 au XIXe.

En plus de « star » déjà cité, voici quelques exemples de mots féminins d'origine anglo-américaine:

- RAM
- Box
- Mainboard
- Start-up

Certains, comme wifi, sont épicènes:

- Une/un interview
- Un/une applet/servlet

On peut aussi noter que l'usage peut parfois différer entre la France et le Québec:

- Un job (F)/ Une job (Q)
- Une auto (F) / Un auto (Q)
- Un sandwich (F) / Une sandwich (Q)

Comment: Par analogie avec Hi-FI on dit souvent *la* Wi-Fi mais https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi le met au masculin

Comment: @cl-r Oui, l'usage majoritaire est le masculin et ce ce que les dictionnaires et assimilés rapportent. Ma réponse explique seulement pourquoi le féminin est souvent entendu.

Comment: @jlliagre , voir ma réponse, moins par référence à la hifi, qu'à la box que voit la majorité des gens. Ce qui en un sens est similaire à la chaîne hifi finalement.

Comment: @guillaumegirod-vitouchkina L'âge du locuteur entre aussi probablement en jeu, « hi-fi » ayant été plus utilisé entre les années 70 et 90 qu'aujourd'hui.

Comment: Comparaisons intéressantes avec le Qc. Une des difficultés est que souvent j'ai du mal à identifier si il y a usage ou simplement usage à l'oral ou simplement faute dans l'[emploi indu](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3772) du masc. pour le féminin. C'est le cas de l'[_auto_](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=2070494) que le GDT dit féminin. Assurément je dis _une job_, mais j'aurais écrit un emploi. La _toast_ mieux que le _sandwich_. Enfin _Franceterme_ encourage _jeune pousse_ et non _start-up_. C'est l'entreprise en démarrage... carte mère. Merci !

Answer (score 4):

Tout dépend de ce que tu entends par "wifi".

Si tu parles du réseau, tu dis le wifi (le réseau wifi).
Si tu parles de la technologie, tu dis la wifi (la technologie wifi).

Answer (score 3):

Je pense qu'il ne faut pas se baser sur l’anglicisme. WIFI n'est pas un anglicisme tout comme le Bluetooth ne sera jamais appelé le dent bleu. 
J'aurais tendance à chercher d'autres exemples dans la langue française. 
Je prendrais comme exemple les marques ou modèles utilisés comme nom. 
On va dire une Rolex (parce que c'est UNE montre),
un karcher (UN nettoyeur haute pression),
une 308 (UNE voiture).

Vous allez me dire oui mais on dit un Scénic, un Espace : 
parce que c'est UN monospace
etc ...

donc comme le WI-FI est utilisé comme UN réseau

ceux qui utilise la wifi sont souvent des personnes qui n'ont pas les connaissances informatique 
comme dit dans un com précédent, ils veulent se connecter à la box wifi, ce qui est un abus de langage sur un abus de langage. 
On ne dit pas une 308 parce qu'elle va sur LA route...

Comment: Wi-Fi signifie "wireless fiber", et on dit bien « une fibre » non ?

Comment: @Stéphane "fiber" ?? Le « fi » signifie « fidelity » mais on dit bien « une fidélité ».

Answer (score 2):

Il y a deux types d'usage courant du mot wifi.

Les personnes les plus averties sur la technologies utilisent le wifi (peut- être en référence au réseau wifi - par opposition, on dit la 2G, la 3G, la 4G, ... pour la téléphonie mobile / la génération).

Les autres / le grand public fait souvent un raccourci avec sa mise en oeuvre, qui passe par un boîtier, communément appelé "la box".

C'est donc la box wifi

Allume la wifi !, éteints, rallume, ...

Connecte-toi à la wifi !

En son absence, on revient au réseau: "tu as du wifi ?"

Answer (score 0):

Je ne pense pas qu'il soit intéressant de répéter les erreurs de l'usage quotidien. Selon le Larousse, il s'agit d'un nom masculin.

Selon [le dictionnaire Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/wi-fi/10910038) :

> ## wi-fi :
>
> nom **masculin** invariable
>
> Réseau local hertzien (sans fil) à haut débit destiné aux liaisons d'équipements informatiques dans un cadre domestique ou professionnel.

Answer (score -2):

En général un anglicisme (emprunt linguistique à l’anglais) est toujours masculin, on dit **le WiFi** (c'est une abréviation commerciale signifiant **Wireless Fidelity** en anglais).

Comment: *Wireless Fidelity* ne signifie rien en anglais, c'est un *backronym*.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi : The Wi-Fi Alliance used the "nonsense" advertising slogan "The Standard for Wireless Fidelity" for a short time after the brand name was invented, leading to the misconception that Wi-Fi was an abbreviation of "Wireless Fidelity".

Answer (score -4):

Tout dépend. Dans le dictionnaire, tu trouveras que WiFI est un nom masculin, mais si tu regardes deux secondes ce que signifie le mot, c'est clairement féminin (en Français, bien évidemment). On a simplement tendance chez nous à mettre du masculin dès que l'on pioche de l'anglicisme (ou autres). Après, "wireless fidelity", clairement, ça sonne pas très viril comme mot... Fidélité, hum ? Même problème avec week-end quand tu y réfléchis ; on a mis ça au masculin intuitivement sauf que, au final, on aurait dû le mettre au féminin. C'est un peu la règle (implicite ou pas, j'en sais rien), mais pour le coup, ça ne me choque pas que certaines personnes emploient le "la" plutôt que le "le". D'un certain côté, ils ont plus raison que nous. x) Comme l'a dit quelqu'un plus haut, tu dis bien une star et pas un star. Parce que bon, un étoile, ça le fait moyen. Un fidélité, ça le fait pas davantage.

Comment: Je ne suis pas sûr d'avoir compris la réponse.